# QGIS label from a polygon layer as a own layer

Tags: qgis, labeling

In my case I have an polygon layer with labels (Beschriftungen). Countries with country names. I want to have this labels as an own point layer without the polygons (countries).

Is this possible? QGIS 2.14

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the polygons to centroids which will contain the same attribute table of the polygon layer, as you can see below:

[image]

Then, create labels from the newly created point layer.

You can find the above tool from `Vector -> Geometry tools -> Polygon centroids`.